# jQuery AJAX Post String to MVC Controller Null Parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a pretty simple AJAX call I am trying to make, which is a search string that will POST a value to a controller as a search string.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/ResultsProcessing/AthleteLookup/n',
    type: 'POST',
    data: searchstring,
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (response) {
         console.log(response);
         if (response) {  // check if data is defined
             //Do something
         }
    }
});
```

However, whatever I try and configure, my controller never receives the string parameter

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AthleteLookup(string searchstring)
```

It is probably something really dumb. But how do I get that search parameter passed to my controller

Comment: Still nothing coming through. `[FromBody]` results in a 415 unsupported media type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your code as below:

```
        $.ajax({ 
            url: '/ResultsProcessing/AthleteLookup',
            type: 'POST', 
            data: { "searchstring": $("#txtSearch").val() }, //get the search string
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response) {  // check if data is defined
                    //Do something
                }
            }
        });
```

Or you could append the search string at the end of the request url, code like this:

[Note] By using this method, there is no need to set the Ajax method to Post and use the `[HttpPost]` attribute in the controller, and we could use the `Get` method.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ResultsProcessing/AthleteLookup/?searchstring=' + $("#txtSearch").val(), 
            type: 'POST',  
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response) {  // check if data is defined
                    //Do something
                }
            }
        });
```

The controller code like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AthleteLookup(string searchstring)
    {
        return new JsonResult("Search string: " + searchstring);
    }
```

The test result as below:

[image]

Comment: In the ajax call, if the type is `POST` then why is the data appended to the URL? Shouldn't that be in the `data` object in the ajax call? like so: `data:  $("#txtSearch").val()`
Does appending the `$("#txtSearch").val()` to the URL make it a GET? or is it still considered a POST request?

Comment: Hi @sagar1025, thank you for pointing it out, if append the parameter to the URL, there is no need to set the Ajax method to `Post` and use the `[HttpPost]` attribute, and we could use the `Get `method.

Comment: Thanks for this - I actually did switch it out to a Get for simplicity. Slightly more RESTful I guess!